# The most / most

Tags: superlative-degree

> He's most approachable first thing in the morning.

I don't understand why I must use "most" and I can't use "The most". 
     I have a little knowledge that "most" is an adverb which amplifies an adjective or a verb.

And "the most" is an adjective which amplifies noun.

Thus, I think "the most" is my answer.

Comment: You can use either.

Comment: https://elt.oup.com/student/oxfordenglishgrammar/advanced/oegc_advanced_section12/advanced_section12_02?cc=th&selLanguage=th                                                              In this web uses "most". I don't understand why it is "most". Could you give me another information ?

Comment: Questions by learners of English may be better asked at https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: _Most_ is indeed an adverb (or a quantifier of degree if you prefer) that can modify adjectives. _Approachable_ is an adjective. _Most approachable_ is thus an adjective phrase. Adjective phrases can be nominalised by adding an article: _they’re rich_ (adj.) becomes _they’re the rich_ (noun phrase meaning ‘the rich people’). Generally these are plurals, but with superlatives they can be singular as well: _he’s richest_ (adj.), _he’s the richest_ (i.e., person). So as Jason says, you can use either, and they mean roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***most***
 adverb

1: to the greatest or highest degree 
— often used with an adjective or adverb to form the superlative.

//the most challenging job he ever had.

2: to a very great degree

//was most persuasive.

So we can use 'most' both with or without the definite article. The choice depends on what you mean in the particular case.

Answer (score 0):

‘Most’ is used with an adjective or adverb to form a superlative. It is whether this superlative is in reference to a *noun* or a *verb* that determines use of the article. When used with the verb ‘to be’, it helps to look at the superlative as referring to either an **object** (noun) or an **action** (verb).

Here is a sentence where the superlative refers to the **object** (noun):

> He’s *the most* approachable on staff.

This sentence uses ‘*the* most’ because the superlative refers to the **object** (an approachable person on staff).

In your sample sentence, however, the superlative refers to the **action**:

> He’s *most* approachable first thing in the morning.

What’s amplified here is the action of *being* approachable at a particular time. This person may be extremely *un*approachable in general.

In the first sentence of user307254’s answer, the superlative refers to the **object** (a challenging *job* he has had), which necessitates ‘*the* most’.

The second sentence refers to the **action** (*being* persuasive) - in this case you would leave off the article.

Answer (score -1):

Briefly, "the most" is used when something is like the best, and just "most" when it is almost the best, let's say, top-10, as far as I know

Comment: No. The difference between _most_ and _the most_ has absolutely nothing to do with whether the thing in question is number one or just in the top ten. They both mean the same thing: number one. Without the article, _most_ can **also** mean ‘very’, but that doesn’t imply any kind of position near the top at all.